# How to check a form field for a specific attribute in that field's m2m key

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that allows the user to pick several vans (many-to-many relationship). Each van has a boolean attribute named "available".  I want to only show the vans whose "available" attribute is set to "True". How do I do this in the forms.py file?

I know that this could possibly be done in the template, but I did not want to create a new form-template with each individual field written out. I wanted to know if this functionality could be done in the forms.py file or in the class based view. I believe that doing it that way would be a bit cleaner. I've look into the validators but I don't think this is the way to go. Maybe I need to run a query set in the form file that checks the attribute before passing it to the form template?

views.py

```
def post(self, request):
        """Take in user data, clean it, and then post it to the database."""
        form = self.form_class(request.POST) # pass in the user's data to that was submitted in form 

        if form.is_valid():
            trip = form.save(commit=False) # create an object so we can clean the data before saving it

            # now get the clean and normalize the data
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            trip_start = form.cleaned_data['trip_start']
            trip_end = form.cleaned_data['trip_end']
            van_used = form.cleaned_data['van_used']
            trip.save()
```

forms.py

```
class TripForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This class will be used to build trips."""

    class Meta:
        """Specifying the database and fields to use."""

        model = trips
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'comments','trip_start', 'trip_end', 'van_used']
```

models.py

```
class trips(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "trips"

    van_used = models.ManyToManyField(vans)

class vans(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "vans"

    vanName = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False)

    # set up how the vans will be referenced in the admin page
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vanName
```

The final form that is rendered would only show the vans whose "available" attribute is set to True. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override queryset for `van_used` field in form like this.

```
class TripForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This class will be used to build trips."""

    class Meta:
        """Specifying the database and fields to use."""

        model = trips
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'comments','trip_start', 'trip_end', 'van_used']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['van_used'].queryset = vans.objects.filter(available=True)
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could manually override queryset in the forms, interesting! thank you for the insight.